# How to get a reference to a Selector in RoboVM?

Tags: robovm

Consider the following line of objective-c code:

```
if ([tableView respondsToSelector:@selector(setSeparatorInset:)])
```

How do you get a reference to the setSeparatorInset selector in RoboVM?

Answer (score 0):

if(tableView.respondsToSelector(Selector.register("setSeparatorInset:")))